# Can Google Cloud Text-to-Speech return the IPA transcription for a word?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

If I send *kittens* to Google Cloud Text-to-Speech can it return `ˈkɪtnz`? I need a Text-to-Speech service that provides both audiofiles and IPA transcriptions. The Oxford English Dictionary and IBM Watson will return both. Can Google Cloud do this?

Comment: Hmm can you tell me more about what you’re using the IPA for?

Comment: The app I'm building uses IPA transcriptions to teach phonology.

Comment: @ThomasDavidKehoe What I can know is IBM TTS API returns IPA.